# Is there a way to select what to import from planet-latest.osm.bz2 to database?

Tags: postgresql, import, select-by-attribute, osm2pgsql

Is there a way to select what to import from planet-latest.osm.bz2 to database?

I want to do something like :

```
osm2pgsql ...  --place='city' --admin_level='2'
```

My goal is to use only cities and countries im my project ( maybe towns ).
I can download many databases with cities and countries shapes from the world, but I think OSM is more complete and if I decide to use other things is just import again.

I just try import all full planet data and then SELECT and INSERT in other database using SQL filters, but its too time-consuming ( and non-professional ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to filter OSM file to another OSM file and then osm2pgsql to import it.  You can do it with single command using pipe as following

```
osmosis --read-pbf planet-latest.osm.bz2 --node-key-value keyValueList="place.city,admin_level.2"  --write-xml - |osm2pgsql --append [my customized arguments] -
```

Comment: I got an "Usage Error" since ommited the filename from osm2pgsql ( I thing its correct ) : D:\osm2pgsql>osmosis --read-pbf-fast south-america.osm.bz2 --node-key-value keyValueList="place.city,admin_level.2"  --write-xml - | osm2pgsql -c -s -d
 OSMTest -U postgres -H 10.5.112.210 -P 5432 -S ./default.style

Comment: @underdark : Thanks for correcting my text, teacher!

Comment: can you explain your answer to me? Still not work because I don't know how to mix you example with my arguments. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is here : [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43239/how-to-manage-the-osmosis-command-line)