# How can I get clean road attributes from OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, network-analyst, fields-attributes, road

I would like to use osm road data for a project where I need to broadly distinguish between primary, secondary, and tertiary roads.

OSM data seems just fine to work with Arcgis' Network Analyst.

When I download data for [WeoGeoMarket](http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/osm-openstreetmap-planet.html), selecting only highways, I face a lot of different classes, sometimes mis-coded (such as 'teriary' instead of 'tertiary').
However, if I visually check on [OSM interactive map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), I can see that the legend is not messy at all.

My question is therefore the following: is it possible to get OSM road data with clean feature attributes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78791/how-to-extract-primary-and-secondary-roads-from-osm-data or this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41965/is-there-a-way-to-select-what-to-import-from-planet-latest-osm-bz2-to-database don't forget to upvote there.

Comment: Every month, we (WeoGeo) take a planet.osm file and using osm2pgsql create a postgres database directly from the Planet file. The content of the data attributes are not edited, so what you get from a WeoGeo download is the data as it had been originally entered into OSM.  

After reviewing our latest database, we are unable to locate any planet_osm_line features where "highway"='teriary'. Could you please provide an osm_id of the feature that is causing problems so that it can be fixed in OSM.

Comment: Thanks Magno C, I wasn't aware of these pages. It will be very helpful. Regarding Robert's remark, I took 'teriary' as an example I found in a previous version of osm data. Having the data under my eyes, I see things such as 'p', 'pah', 'kadjeke', etc. However, it concerns a small minority of records (at the African scale). Thanks for the clarifications about how the data are processed by WeoGeo, this is very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your replies.
Regarding my question, it seems that the answer is a combination of a knowledge of [osm key for highways](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway) and waiting for the latest revision of WeoGeo data.